# Try to get Hibernate SessionFactory with sprint-boot-jpa V1.4.1

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I try to initiate a bean with the SessionFactory of hibernate but spring don't provide the EntityManagerFactory. I want to use Spring boot V1.4.1
It run with spring boot V1.3.3

My main configuration file :

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.class})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ServletComponentScan
@EnableOAuth2Client
@ComponentScan(value = "com.wps.artemis.dto", basePackageClasses = {Application.class, DatabaseConfig.class})
@Import({DatabaseConfig.class})
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableMongoRepositories
@EntityScan("com.fdilogbox.artemis.model")
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.oauth2.client")
    @Primary
    public ClientCredentialsResourceDetails oauth2ClientCredentialsResourceDetails() {
    return new ClientCredentialsResourceDetails();
    }
}
```

My configuration class for database :

```
@Configuration
@EntityScan("com.fdilogbox.artemis.model")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.wps.artemis")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatabaseConfig {

    public DatabaseConfig() {
        System.out.println("Ici");
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return ((HibernateEntityManagerFactory)entityManagerFactory).getSessionFactory();
    }
}
```

My configuration file :

```
spring:
    data:
        jpa:
          repositories:
            enabled: false

    datasource:
        driver-class-name: com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver
        url: jdbc:as400://192.168.100.136/ART_TST_DV
        username: login
        password: pass
        test-while-idle: true
        test-on-borrow: true
        validation-query: SELECT 1 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
    jpa:
        properties:
            hibernate:
                dialect: com.fdilogbox.db.dialect.FdiDB2400Dialect
                default_schema: ART_TST_DV
                format_sql: false
                generate_statistics: false
                current_session_context_class: org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext
                ddl-auto: none
                cache:
                    provider_class: net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheProvider
                    use_query_cache: true
                   use_second_level_cache: true
                    region:
                        factory_class: org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
        hibernate:
            naming:
                physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImplnter code here
```

The spring boot error :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'application': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory': Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/wps/artemis/database/config/DatabaseConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'sessionFactory' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitRootLocation(Ljava/lang/String;)V; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitRootLocation(Ljava/lang/String;)V; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/wps/artemis/database/config/DatabaseConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'sessionFactory' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitRootLocation(Ljava/lang/String;)V; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitRootLocation(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:569) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:372) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.initMessageSource(AbstractApplicationContext.java:707) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:529) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at com.wps.artemis.ihm.Application.main(Application.java:56) [classes/:?]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/wps/artemis/database/config/DatabaseConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'sessionFactory' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitRootLocation(Ljava/lang/String;)V; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitRootLocation(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1054) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1019) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:566) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
... 27 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitRootLocation(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1054) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1019) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1054) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1019) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:566) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
... 27 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitRootLocation(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1054) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1019) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1054) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1019) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:566) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitRootLocation(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder$Builder.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder.java:209) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.entityManagerFactory(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:128) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    .....
```

Comment: Remove the spring version use the spring boot provided one. Also you are trying very hard not to use spring boot with all the annotaitons (most of which spring boot automatically detects).

Comment: It was the error. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Remove spring and hibernate version resolve the problem